# BAM file filteing to remain best isoform

Tags: sequence-alignment, sam, sequence-annotation, rna-splicing, isoform

I ran HiSat2, MarkDuplicate, removed reads with the lower quality score than 40 and finally only kept properly paired reads.

After the BAM filtering steps, I used the Scallop results with TransDecoder. Next, I used bamCoverage to create RNA-Seq profile. I noticed that not always the first isoform is the best one compared to the RNA-Seq profile as could be seen below a few examples:

1.
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-22 at 4 35 26 PM]

2.
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-22 at 4 38 45 PM]

3.
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-22 at 4 51 37 PM]

4.
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-22 at 4 58 42 PM]

5.
[image: Screen Shot 2020-08-22 at 5 04 34 PM]

By any chance, is there a way to keep only the best isoform which is in red box?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I'm not familiar with Scallop/TransDecoder, but it would be helpful to know what you mean by "best". I think I agree with you about which one is "best" but formulating a specific quantitative definition of "best" would be a good first step. Is there any definition of "best" in these tools? How would they evaluate what is "best"?

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional information was too long to post them on this side, Therefore, I posted them [here](https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/issues/111#issuecomment-685267466)